# Не приходят SSH-пакеты на VM ubuntu-server 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox

Я пытаюсь настроить SSH-сервер на убунте, но пингуя айпишник сервера - в консоли Connection refused , а вм сама на себя нормально коннектится.

С вм можно пингануть пк и наоборот.
Выключенный фаервол - не помогает

UPD: Супер тупое решение проблемы - перепутал в пробросе портов адресса хост айпи и гостевого айпи
[image]

Comment: Ну а порт-то ssh открыт?

Comment: @donRumata работоспособность подключения к самому себе и выключенный фаервол намекают, что открыт

Comment: @andreymal, нет не намекают. Ссх может быть сконфигурен слушать только локалхост.

Comment: @donRumata по умолчанию в убунте он слушает всё, и я подозреваю, что автор в конфиги sshd не лез

Comment: @donRumata кроме того, ошибка Connection timed out говорит о том, что запрос до сервера в принципе не дошёл (иначе бы было какое-нибудь Connection refused), так что проблему нужно искать не в конфигах ssh, а где-нибудь ещё (например, в фаерволе, который по какой-то причине оказался всё-таки не выключен)